# Azure API Manager "USage Quota Per Subscription" Policy

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

The policy syntax is as below -

```
<quota calls="number" bandwidth="kilobytes" renewal-period="seconds">  
    <api name="API name" id="API id" calls="number" renewal-period="seconds" />  
        <operation name="operation name" id="operation id" calls="number" renewal-period="seconds" />  
    </api>  
</quota>
```

I have a specific question related to the renewal period. As per documentation, it's

> The time period in seconds after which the quota resets

Suppose I want the quota to reset every day. I put the value of renewal period as = `(60*60*24= 86400)`. When would this limit kick in? Would it be reset exactly 24 hours from the time the policy becomes effective? So if I want the quota to reset at midnight, I have to make sure that the policy gets into effect at midnight?

Answer (score 0):

the renewal starts to count down after the quota limit is reached. So in this case, configuring a renewal of 24 hours, if you reach your quota on 11/09/2018 13:00, then you will be able to request it again only on 12/09/2018 13:00.